# In Harry Potter, who mints the money?

Tags: harry-potter

Who mints the money in Harry Potter?

Is it the Ministry, Gringott's or some other entity?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Goblins, presumably in the employ of Gringotts

This is stated explicitly in *Order of the Phoenix*, when describing Hermione's charmed Galleons (emphasis mine):

> "You see the numerals around the edge of the coins?" Hermione said, holding one up for examination at the end of their fourth meeting. The coin gleamed fat and yellow in the light from the torches. "**On real Galleons that’s just a serial number referring to the goblin who cast the coin.**
>
> <sup>*Order of the Phoenix* Chapter 19: "The Lion and the Serpent"</sup>

While it's not said outright that goblin coinmakers are employed by Gringotts, the nature of commerce suggests that they're in some kind of economic relationship, whether they're direct employees or tradesgoblins filling commissions.